# Python: columns minimum of nested list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I am running a calculation between two dataframes, getting a nested list as a result. Since I try to keep the performance up, I apply vectorisation to the bigger dataframe and looping over the smaller dataframe.

My result is a nested list with a length of 600. However, every item consists of an array of length 100,000.

My goal is to have a new list or np.series with all minimum values per column (so 100,000 minimum values out of 600 rows). Any idea how to do this?

```
list
[array([ 70.3219239 ,  71.17387028,  69.90496498, ...,  85.68666008,
         16.72193348, 123.36816359]),
 array([138.32970088, 137.10783977, 138.64876503, ..., 210.72072939,
        217.60846122, 107.94615237]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have data like this:

```
data = np.array([[2.884, 1.033, 0.066, 7.216],
                 [1.652, 3.255, 7.805, 7.894],
                 [2.663, 6.205, 0.226, 0.484]])

>>> data.min()         # gives minimal value from all rows and columns
0.066

>>> data.min(axis=0)   # gives vector of minimal values for each column
array([1.652, 1.033, 0.066, 0.484])

>>> data.min(axis=1)   # gives vector of minimal values for each row
array([0.066, 1.652, 0.226])
```